# How to remove "Client-Peer" (etc) header in nginx with php-fastcgi

Tags: nginx, http-headers

**My setup:**

- OS: Ubuntu 11.04
- HTTP Server: nginx 1.2.1

  - compiled with the [HttpHeadersMore](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module
  - processing PHP via php-fastcgi
- (other irrelevant software - ruby, python, etc)

**My problem:**

I'm trying to completely mask the software which serves the pages (partly security, mostly because it's fun), I've managed to change the server name and remove the `X-Powered-By` header which php-fastcgi adds, but I'm having trouble removing three headers:

```
Client-Date: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 20:32:34 GMT
Client-Peer: 205.186.146.37:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
```

I have used `more_clear_headers` from the HttpHeadersMore module but that has no effect, despite being able to remove the `X-Powered-By` headers.

This is in my `http` block

```
more_set_headers "Server: Tesco Value";
more_clear_headers "X-Powered-By";
more_clear_headers "Client-*";
more_clear_headers "Client-Date";
more_clear_headers "Client-Response-Num";
more_clear_headers "Client-Peer";
more_clear_headers "X-Pingback";

add_header X-Required-Volume-Setting 11;
add_header X-Required-Speed 88mph;

# NEW: added in thanks to the answer from @kworr - but still doesn't work
fastcgi_hide_header "Client-Date";
fastcgi_hide_header "Client-Response-Num";
fastcgi_hide_header "Client-Peer";
```

If you run `HEAD slightlymore.co.uk` you'll see that neither explicit nor wildcard rules get rid of the header. I'm guessing that these headers are set after the `output-header-filter` phase - but I'd like to know if anyone has any more information on this, and especially if anyone has a solution.

**UPDATE**

@kworr suggested that [fastcgi_hide_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_hide_header) might be what I'm looking for - but still doesn't work. Perhaps it's just my system?

Answer (score 1):

Those headers were not present in the HTTP response at all. Neither nginx nor php-fpm ever sent them, so trying to block them is pointless.

They are synthetic response headers *added* to the response by your user agent, libwww-perl.

If you don't wish to see them, make HTTP requests with some other library, such as libcurl.

Answer (score 0):

I think [fastcgi_hide_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_hide_header) is what you really need.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work either. I tried replacing `more_clear_headers`, using it as well as `more_clear_headers`, and tried all the different contexts, but the headers are still there :( Question updated accordingly.

Comment: Your Nginx has to include the "headers more" [module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module). You can check if it's built using with "nginx -V" - look for "headers-more-nginx-module" in the output. Building Nginx is [easy](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source). Once that's done this is an example of a working way to clear headers : more_clear_headers Server;

Comment: The fastcgi_hide_header is what worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today.

I solved the  problem with `fastcgi_param` and set blank (`''`) value for fastcgi-`variable`, created from prefix `HTTP_` + uppercased request header.

Example for header `Client-Peer`:

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_CLIENT_PEER '';
```